# What should I consider when storing a light aircraft outdoors for several months?

Tags: cessna-152

I would like to store a Cessna outside for a period of time, close to six months. The temperature here will not exceed 30°C and will not go below 0°C.

With tie downs and a tarp, how long can I store a Cessna outside for in these conditions? Should I invest in a shed of some sort? I would prefer a specific period of time please.

Comment: Are you able to go out and start it a couple times a month? Is there a local FBO that can check on it? Maybe a pilot friend can run it around the patch every month or so? Is it flyable?

Comment: Surely there are more factors than just temperature. Things like humidity (mold), precipitation, insects (wasps), reptiles (snakes), small (mouse) and large (bear) mammals?

Comment: @RonBeyer, yes, pilot mate can start it when needed. Yes it is flyable.

Comment: I am not a real pilot, but from flight simulation I know, that after a month without operation, the oil get's black and it acts like an acid. So, be sure to remove the oil if you don't want a corroded plane.

Comment: Flying is the best thing for an airplane, rather than storing it for months as it will air out the frame and wings.

Comment: @NoahKrasser That is false, you don't want to store an aircraft (or aircraft engine) without oil in it. Oil just doesn't break down that fast, and I'm not sure I've ever heard of it "acting like an acid".

Comment: @RonBeyer I really can be wrong. And it just was an assumption to remove the oil from the engine. Maybe you know the A2A Cessna 182 for flight sim. If not: It's modelled like the real thing and in the handbook they say, that after around a month of no operation, the oil gets black and corrodes parts of the engine. I guess this is true, because the intention of the A2A C182 is to provide a training aircraft for the real world in the home flight sim. But if you say one doesn't want to store an aircraft w/o oil, then I guess it's good to start the engine every month and let it run a bit.

Comment: @NoahKrasser I own a Cessna 177B which sits unused some months (winter ones mostly), when we change the oil (three times a year at most), the oil gets sent off for analysis. It always comes back fine. My A&P just recommends we run it around the patch at least once every 45 days and keep the battery on a maintenance charger. Oil manufacturers recommend oil changes every 50 hours or 4 months. Acids in the oil (if found) are caused by piston blow-by, not degradation of the oil. In an otherwise healthy engine, you should not have fuel in the oil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you in a wet or coastal environment?  You can store a "Cessna type" plane outside for a few months and be ok.  Most flight school planes live outside for years and do just fine.

Don't use a tarp.  You might damage antennas, windows, or paint.  Custom fitted covers are good but they're also expensive.

Don't just start the plane and let it idle.  That hurts the engine more than it helps.  To do any good, the engine must reach and sustain normal operating temperature until the moisture boils off.  A quick flight can accomplish this.